# Merging two dataframes with multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For some reason, I can't quite determine why Pandas is not merging my two dataframes. I've followed several other solutions, but I'm still not getting the expected output.

My main dataframe, `df`, has basketball player data and is quite large with 10000+ rows. Here is a snippet of `df`:

```
    Date           Team  
    12/10/2020      BOS
    12/10/2020      ATL
    12/10/2020      PHI
    12/11/2020      BOS
    12/11/2020      ATL
    12/11/2020      PHI
```

My second dataframe, `ps`, is much smaller with 1000 rows and has team information:

```
    Date            Team  Points  H/A
    12/10/2020      ATL   70      1
    12/10/2020      PHI   120     1
    12/10/2020      BOS   100     0
    12/11/2020      BOS   110     0
    12/11/2020      PHI   93      1
    12/11/2020      ATL   104     0
```

Expected output of `df` after matching `df` and `ps`:

```
    Date            Team  Points  H/A
    12/10/2020      BOS   100     0
    12/10/2020      ATL   70      1
    12/10/2020      PHI   120     1
    12/11/2020      BOS   110     0
    12/11/2020      ATL   104     0
    12/11/2020      PHI   93      1
```

My attempts:
`pd.merge(df,ps, on=['Team','Date'])`
`df = pd.merge(df,ps, on=['Team','Date'])` which I believe is the same thing as above, just assigning `df` again.

When I do either of the above and save `df` to a CSV, `ps` headers and data don't appear anywhere in `df`. I would like to merge `ps` with `df`, matching on "Date" and "Team", so that every player in `df` has a corresponding value from `ps` columns "Points" and "H/A". I  should note that the dates are not in chronological order in either dataset, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @chitown88 I appreciate the offer! One of my datasets had the date processed via `df.apply(lambda x: datetime.date(x['Year'], x['Month'], x['Day']), axis=1)` and was an object datatype and not datetime as I expected. Making sure the dates in both datasets were of type datetime fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['12/10/2020']*3 + ['12/11/2020']*3,
                   'Team': ['BOS', 'ATL', 'PHI', 'BOS', 'ATL', 'PHI']})


ps = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['12/10/2020']*3 + ['12/11/2020']*3,
                   'Team': ['ATL', 'PHI', 'BOS', 'BOS', 'PHI', 'ATL'],
                   'Points': [70, 120, 100, 110, 93, 104],
                   'H/A': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]})

df = pd.merge(df,ps, on=['Team','Date'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
         Date Team  Points  H/A
0  12/10/2020  BOS     100    0
1  12/10/2020  ATL      70    1
2  12/10/2020  PHI     120    1
3  12/11/2020  BOS     110    0
4  12/11/2020  ATL     104    0
5  12/11/2020  PHI      93    1
```

Comment: Thanks! At least I know I am on the right track... I suspect now that I have some datatype or other fouling of my dataframes that's preventing the merge from happening correctly.